# django render_to_response on google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am experiencing a weird issue using Django on Google App Engine. I have a file upload form defined within a django-app like this:

```
class ConvertForm(forms.Form):
    from = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices_from,
                                label='from:')
    to = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices_to,
                              label='to:')
    class Meta:
        fields = ('from','to')
```

And then I have in my app.views file the following:

```
def convert(request):

   if request.POST:
       form = ConvertForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

       if form.is_valid():
           from = form.cleaned_data['from']
           to = form.cleaned_data['to']       

           # Redirect to a result page after post to avoid duplicates          
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/convert/results')
    else:
        form = ConvertForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form']=form                       
    return render_to_response('convert.html',args)
```

The form-part of my convert.html template looks like this:

```
<form action="/convert/convert/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{%\
 csrf_token %}
  <ul>
    {{ form.as_ul }}
  </ul>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Convert">
</form>
```

It's supposed to be a file-upload form (hence the multipart), but I edited the form-contents for brevity.

Now, when I browse the proper url, nothing happens. I can clearly see that the correct functions are being called, since replacing the body of the convert() function with a simple

```
return render_to_response('convert_test.html',{'some_text':some_text})
```

displays the value of some_text in the browser window. Is there any additional quirks when dealing with forms within GAE that I am missing, or why isn't convert.html being rendered with the form? I should mention that all of this is on localhost, I haven't deployed it yet.

Edit: After some more fiddling around with this, it seems that maybe the source of the error is in the inheritance of templates. If I take out all django-tags {} in the convert.html, I can get the form to render correctly. 
So, the question is now how do I properly set up template inheritance within GAE?

My full convert.html template looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h2>[ convert ]</h2>
<form action="/convert/convert/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% \
csrf_token %}
  <ul>
    {{ form.as_ul }}
  </ul>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Convert">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

So basically redefining the content block of the base.html template. This was working perfectly before I tested it on GAE, so I can't shake the feeling that's involved somehow.

If it is relevant, my django settings.py looks like this for the templates:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..','convert','templates'),
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..','templates'),                 
)
```

And as I said, taking out the {}-tags from convert.html gives me the form, but rendered on its own in an otherwise completely white and empty page.

This is the contents of my base.html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/\
DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="Your description goes here" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="your,keywords,goes,here" />
        <meta name="author" content="Your Name" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/basic-minimal.css" ti\
tle="Basic Minimal" media="all" />

        <title>Basic Minimal v1.2</title>
</head>

<body class="light">
<div id="wrap">
        <div id="header">
                <h1><a href="/convert/main">[ snazzy title ]</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar">
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="/convert/convert">[ Convert ]</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/convert/transform">[ Transform ]</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/convert/help">[ Help ]</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/convert/references">[ References ]</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <h2>[ more title ]</h2>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>More text</p>
        </div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works beautifully for the "title" page (even the css gets loaded), but rendering other templates as convert.html above using this as a base does not work.

Comment: You can use the browser's debugger to see if the page returned anything at all.  Most likely it returned some html but not the form.  Try setting up your template so that you see at least some text.  Most likely the choices you passed into the ChoiceFields are problematic.

Comment: Thanks - tried that. It seems that whenever I include the {% extends "base.html" %} at the top of convert.html, things break and I get back the contents of my base.html (properly rendered). Leaving out {% extends "base.html" %} gives me back the html I have in my template.

Comment: You should show your full template then. If you're extending from a base template, you need to define the blocks in the base and override them in the child: anything in the child that's not in a block defined in the parent will not show. This is basic Django, nothing to do with GAE.

Comment: Just for a test: show us the contents of base (maybe something is missing there) and put base.html and convert.html in the same folder

Comment: And I have also tested moving everything to the same directory to no avail. Neither having all template files in the project-directory, or having them all in the template directory of the app doesn't work. Other suggestions?

Comment: Ok, found the problem. Somewhere along the road, the {}-tags had vanished form the base.html template. They need to be there obviously :-) Thanks to all!